# How can I change shortcuts for GNOME Shell Screen Recorder in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, desktop-recording

I use <kbd>Shift</kbd> key for switching languages, so I can't use other shortcuts with <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Recently I need to record my desktop and can't do this.

In **Settings** -> *Devices* -> *Keyboard* on this action not opening subwindow to change this shortcuts (not all shortcuts can be changed in this place).

So how or where I can change this (better all) shortcut(s)? In which file is or something like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch Terminal and run the following command

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screencast
```

It should return the current keyboard shortcut. The default one should be `'<Ctrl><Shift><Alt>R'`.

You can set a new keyboard shortcut by running

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screencast YOUR-PREFERRED-KEY-COMBINATION
```

Note that you need to follow syntax as returned by the first command. For example, to set <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (in place of <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), you need to use `'<Ctrl><Alt>R'` in place of `YOUR-PREFERRED-KEY-COMBINATION` in the command above, i.e. you need to run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screencast '<Ctrl><Alt>R'
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, 

`gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screencast`

errors as

`No such key “screencast”`

. What's wrong? In the mean time I managed to perform the override via GNOME "Settings" => "Keyboard" => "Keyboard Shortcuts" => "Record a screencast interactively".